# sum of two elements in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose I have a commutative ring $R$ with unity.
And suppose we have three elements $a, b, c \in R$
such that $a+b = c$.

Is it possible that there are two units $\epsilon, \epsilon'$ (not both $1$)
such that $\epsilon a + \epsilon'b = c$?

Thanks!

Comment: So you've accepted *an example* of $R,a,b,c,\epsilon,\epsilon'$ as an answer, but your original question made it sound as if you were asking if given $a,b,c,R$ that it was always possible to find such $\epsilon,\epsilon'$. If that was really what you were looking for you should be more careful to be clear next time :)

Comment: You are perfectly right! My apologies for the confusion. And thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R=\Bbb {Z/8Z}, a=1, b=2, c=3, \epsilon=1, \epsilon'=5$

If $b(\epsilon'-1)=0$ (among other ways) you are there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for every ring.

In $\Bbb F_2$, $1+0=1$, but you **cannot** find any units $\epsilon,\epsilon'$ with the properties you want.

More generally in any Boolean ring (with identity), and any $a+b=c$, you still can't accomplish the task, because the only unit available is the identity in a Boolean ring.